# Retain tooltip of previous layer in Altair

Tags: python, vega, altair, vega-lite

I am adding states outline overlay on my choropleth plot in altair 
My choropleth plot has tooltip for it. 
When I layer the state outline on top of the choropleth I lose the tooltip feature of the plot 
Anyone have ideas on how to handle this? 
Any help would be appreciated

```
import altair as alt

# saving data into a file rather than embedding into the chart
alt.data_transformers.enable('json') 
alt.renderers.enable('notebook')
# alt.renderers.enable('jupyterlab')
from vega_datasets import data
import pandas as pd
from altair import Scale,Color

states = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, 'states')
counties = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url+'#', 'counties')

dummy='#dbe9f6'
scheme='blues'
type1='linear'

fg = alt.Chart(counties).mark_geoshape(
        stroke='black',
        strokeWidth=0.05
    ).project(
        type='albersUsa'
    ).transform_lookup(
        lookup='id',
        from_=alt.LookupData(fdf, 'fips', ['year','Pill_per_pop','BUYER_COUNTY', 'state'])
    ).transform_calculate(
        Pill_per_pop='isValid(datum.Pill_per_pop) ? datum.Pill_per_pop : -1'  
    ).encode(
        color = alt.condition(
            'datum.Pill_per_pop > 0',
            alt.Color('Pill_per_pop:Q', scale=Scale(scheme=scheme,type=type1)),
            alt.value(dummy)
            ),
        tooltip=['BUYER_COUNTY:N', 'state:N','Pill_per_pop:Q','year:Q']
    ).properties(
        width=700,
        height=400,
        title='Pills per 100k people'
)

outline = alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape(stroke='black',strokeWidth=0.2).project(
    type='albersUsa'
    )

fg+outline
```

My output
[image]

However I am unable to find a way to retain the tooltip of the previous layer i.e. county level map

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out 
Define a new chart as follows:

```
fg1 = alt.Chart(counties).mark_geoshape(
        stroke='black',
        strokeWidth=0.05
    ).project(
        type='albersUsa'
    ).transform_lookup(
        lookup='id',
        from_=alt.LookupData(fdf, 'fips', ['year','Pill_per_pop','BUYER_COUNTY', 'state'])
    ).transform_calculate(
        Pill_per_pop='isValid(datum.Pill_per_pop) ? datum.Pill_per_pop : -1'  
    ).encode(        
        tooltip=['BUYER_COUNTY:N', 'state:N','Pill_per_pop:Q','year:Q']
    ).properties(
        width=700,
        height=400,
        title='Pills per 100k people'
)

fg+outline+fg1
```

Just define the chart again with encoding for tool-tip and not for color and layer it on top of the above chart.